# Python discord bot that calls the google sheets API issue

Tags: python, api, google-sheets

I'm running into a weird error randomly now on my discord bot. It uses python and just calls the Google Sheets API and prints the information that it finds in a range of cells. I have it currently running on a raspberry pi in the other room and it's working fine on there but I cannot create another instance of the bot anywhere so I'm afraid of restarting the raspberry pi (in case it can't log back in). I used to be able to have multiple instances of the bot running so that's whhat's confusing me a bit.

Here is the code for the authorization:

```
import pickle
import os.path    
from googleapiclient.discovery import build    
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request   
from discord import Game

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly']
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'my spreadsheet'    
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'league!A2:R'     
TOKEN = 'Token generated a while back'

client = discord.Client()
channel = client.get_channel('my channel')
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
```

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUurO.png)

I spent some time researching what might be the issue and it said there might be something wrong with the Google sheets authentication token but none of those suggested fixes seemed to work. I would greatly appreciate any help with this because I'm pretty new to python.

Comment: Have you tried using the API explorer to verify if you have the right parameters when making the request? And also, in which line does the code fail?

Comment: I did take a look into the API documentation and reset my workspace completely (uninstalled python and reinstalled all of the required files) and it is working now. I think one of the files got corrupted or something. Thank you for replying though.

Answer (score 0):

The pip and googleAPI files must have gotten corrupted somehow because completely destroying and resetting my workspace appears to have fixed it.